Determine if a given language L is in RE and prove it
Can someone please help me solve this problem?
Let $HP = \{ \langle M, w\rangle: \text{$M$ is a Turing machine that halts on input $w$}\}$ denote the halting problem, and consider
the language:
$$L_2 = \{\langle M \rangle : \text{$M$ is a Turing machine and }\overline{HP} \leq L(M)\}$$
Choose one of the following. The language $L_2$ is:

trivial.
a non-trivial language in $\text{R}$.
in $\text{RE}\setminus \text{R}$.
in $\overline{RE}$.

Prove the determined answer.
I think it is 4, not in $\text{RE}$,  but I am not sure how to prove it.

Define $\overline{HP}$.

The correct answer is 0. Note that for every TM $M$, it holds by definition that $L(M)\in \text{RE}$ as every machine recognizes its own language. Therefore, there are no machines with $\overline{HP}\leq L(M)$. Indeed, otherwise, we get that the complement of halting problem $\overline{HP}$ is in $\text{RE}$ as well. So the language $L_2$ must be empty.
